# гиперссылка в телеграме не скрывается

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

вот код который подгружает картинку по ссылке. Как можно скрыть ссылку которая выводится над картинкой?

`(..)[http://*]` не работает, выводит всё это как текст
`<a href="http://*">..</a>` тоже  не работает, выводит всё это как текст

```
#вставка картинки
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['pic'])
def url(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/An-orange-cat-sniffing-catnip.jpg", reply_markup = markup)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка отображается из-за того, что вы используете метод `send_message` вместо метода `send_photo` подробнее о методе в [Telegram api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) и в [документации](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) к используемой вами библиотеке.